# Prove that each $R \in SO(3)$ has exactly 2 preimages with respect to the covering map $\Phi_U : SU(2) \rightarrow SO(3)$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, group-homomorphism, covering-spaces

> Prove that each $R \in SO(3)$ has exactly 2 preimages with respect to the covering map $\Phi_U : SU(2) \rightarrow SO(3)$

I tried in this way:

Let's consider $U \in SU(2)$ and $X \in V = i su(2)$

\begin{array}{ccc}
&&
\text{U =} &
\begin{bmatrix}
    \alpha & \beta\\
-\beta^{*} &  \alpha^{*}
\end{bmatrix} &
\text{$\alpha$, $\beta$  $\in \mathbb{C}$, $|\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2 = 1$} &
&&
\end{array}

\begin{array}{ccc}
& &  \\
&  \\
\text{X = } &
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_1 & x_2+ix_3 \\
x_2 - ix_3 & -x_1\\
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{array}

where $x_1, x_2, x_3$ are the coordinates of a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

$$\Phi : SU(2) \rightarrow SO(3)$$
is given by $\Phi_U(X) = U X U^{-1}$ and

\begin{array}{ccc}
\text{$\Phi_U$ = } &
\begin{bmatrix}
    |\alpha|^2 - |\beta|^2 & -2Re(\alpha \beta) & 2 Im( \alpha \beta) \\
    2Re(\alpha \beta) & Re(\alpha^2 - \beta^2) & Im(\beta^2 - \alpha^2) \\
    2Im(\alpha \beta) & Im(\alpha^2 + \beta^2) & Re(\alpha^2 + \beta^2)
\end{bmatrix} &
\end{array}

$\Phi$ (i.e. the map $U \rightarrow \Phi_U$) is a Lie group homomorphism of $SU(2)$ into $SO(3)$ which is surjective. Moreover its kernel is:
$$ \text{Ker} \Phi =: K = \{ -\text{Id}, \text{Id} \}$$
Indeed $\Phi_U = \text{Id}$ means $\Phi_U(X) = X = U X U^{-1}$,   i.e. $UX = XU$ for all $U$, so $U$ should be a multiple of the identity matrix, and since $\text{det}(Id)=1$ and $U \in SU(2)$, this implies $U= \pm Id$.

So by a theorem related to universal covering maps between group, we know that, since $SO(3)$ is a connected Lie group, then $SU(2)$ is the unique simply connected Lie group and $\Phi$ is the unique Lie group homomorphism that is surjective, such that:
$$SO(3) \cong SU(2)/ K$$

As $\Phi$ is surjective, every $R \in SO(3)$ has a preimage. Then, by definition, if $\Phi_U = R$, $\Phi_{-U} = R$ too. Cannot be more than two because $SO(3) \cong SU(2)/K$ means that $$SO(3) = \text{Id} \hspace{2mm} SU(2) \cup (-\text{Id}) \hspace{2mm} SU(2)$$

This proves the statement.
Is my proof correct?

Comment: What does $|G|$ mean here? The dimensions of these Lie groups are both $3$.

Comment: [Related!](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2233834/272127)

Comment: I find it a bit confusing. The principle seems to be right but what are your maps exactly? Consider the transformation $$\operatorname{Ad}\, : \,g\longmapsto (X\longmapsto 
 gXg^{-1})$$ and check the kernel.

Comment: Edited my post and modified my proof

Answer (score 1):

The transformation in question is for $g=\begin{bmatrix}z &-\overline{w}\\ w & \overline{z}\end{bmatrix}$ with $|z|^2+|w|^2=1$ and $$
\operatorname{Ad}\, : \,\operatorname{SU}(2,\mathbb{C})\longrightarrow \operatorname{SO}\left(\mathfrak{su}_\mathbb{R}(2,\mathbb{C})\right)=\operatorname{SO}(3,\mathbb{R})
$$
given by $\operatorname{Ad}(g)(X)=gXg^{-1}$
\begin{equation}\operatorname{Ad}(g) = \begin{bmatrix} \mathfrak{Re}(z^2-w^2)&\mathfrak{Im}(z^2-w^2)&2\; \mathfrak{Re}(w \cdot \bar{z})\\[6pt] -\, \mathfrak{Im}(z^2+w^2)&\mathfrak{Re}(z^2+w^2)&2\; \mathfrak{Im}(w \cdot \bar{z})\\[6pt] -2\; \mathfrak{Re}(w \cdot z)&-2\; \mathfrak{Im}(w \cdot z)& |z|^2-|w|^2 \end{bmatrix} \end{equation}
according to the basis
\begin{equation}\label{S-II} \sigma_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\, , \, \sigma_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -i \\ i & 0 \end{bmatrix}\, , \, \sigma_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix} \end{equation}

Comment: Very nice that you used the Pauli matrices!

Comment: What is exactly $X$?

Comment: Edited my post and modified my proof

Comment: If you want to apply the matrix of $\operatorname{Ad}(g)$ then you need a vector. $X=x_1\sigma_1+x_2\sigma_2+x_3\sigma_3$ is such a vector. The Pauli matrices are the basis of $\operatorname{SO}(3), X=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ a generic vector. We have to prove that $\{g\in \operatorname{SU}(2)\,|\,\operatorname{Ad}(g)\cdot X=0\text{ for all }X\in\operatorname{SO}(3)\}=\{\pm \mathbb{1}\}\cong \mathbb{Z}_2.$

Comment: corr.: $\{g\in \operatorname{SU}(2)\,|\,\operatorname{Ad}(g)\cdot X=0 \text{ for all }X\in \mathbb{R}^3\}=\{\pm 1\}.$

Comment: I'm not getting your point, I have not to prove which is the Kernel, I have to assume that consists of $+1$ and $-1$.

Comment: Is it my proof correct?

Comment: More or less. 1) Substitute $X$ by $iX$ since $SU(2)$ operates on its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2)=\{X+\bar{X}^*=0\wedge \operatorname{trace}(X)=0\}$ which are the skew-hermitian matrices. 2) Why is the kernel $\{\pm 1\}$? You claim it, you didn't prove it. Instead simply show that $\Phi_U(X)=\Phi_U(-X).$

Comment: we defined $su(2)$ as the antiself adjoint matrices with trace 0, so I used $X$ instead of $iX$, as my professor and Brian Hall in its book do.

Comment: Furthermore I have not to prove which is the kernel. I would like to do it but seems not trivial. Moreover I changed my proof a little bit to make it simplier. Could you please help me to improve it? I have to present it to my class.

Comment: @MariusS.L. could you answer,please?

Comment: Looks good. I would set $K:=\ker \Phi$ at the first occurrence and then only use $K$ from there on. Do not mix it. I would also prove $K=\pm 1.$ It's easy: $Ad(X)=\operatorname{Id}$ means $Ad(X)(U) = XUX^{-1}=U$ i.e. $UX=XU$ for all $U.$ The end is a bit weird. We have $SU(2)/K=SO(i\mathbb{R}^3)=SO(3).$ $Ad$ is surjective, so every $R\in SO(3)$ has a preimage. If $Ad(X)=R$ then $Ad(-X)=R,$ too, which are the two preimages: $\pm X$. It can't be more than two since $SO(3) \stackrel{1:1}{=} (+1)\cdot SU(2) \cup (-1)\cdot SU(2).$  Maybe you should also show that $\Phi_U \in SO(3).$

Comment: @MariusS.L. modified my post once more time, hope it's correct now.
I didn't show that $\Phi_U \in SO(3)$ because we already did it during the lectures

Comment: Yes, except that you need to add that $XU=UX $for all $U$ requires $X$ to be a multiple of the identity matrix, and since $\det I=1,$ therefore $X=\pm 1.$ And I confused the groups, sorry. We have $SU(2)=SO(3)\ltimes K = SO(3) \cup -SO(3).$

Comment: @MariusS.L. Modified last things. Could you explain me why the last formula that you write implies the statement?

Comment: a) You can use Schur's lemma for $XU=UX\,\forall U $ implies $X=c\cdot \mathbb{R}$ IIRC or calculate it by choosing suitable $U.$ b) We have $SU(2)/K\cong SO(3)$ so $SU(2)=K\times SO(3)$ as sets. It would hold true for abelian groups, too, but we don't have commutativity. Instead, we get a semidirect product $SO(3) \ltimes K$ with a normal subgroup $K$ (since it is a kernel of a group homomorphism) and a subgroup $SO(3)$ (since it is an image of a  group homomorphism). That's basic group theory.

Comment: No ok this was clear, what I didn't understand why the fact that $SU(2) = SO(3) \cup - SO(3)$ implies the double preimages

Comment: $SU(2)=SO(3)\ltimes K=SO(3)\ltimes \{\pm 1\}=\{(SO(3),+1)\}\cup \{(SO(3),-1)\}.$ The notation $-SO(3)$ for the set theoretical pair $(SO(3),-1)$ is just a bit sloppy. These equations also show what is meant by a double cover.

Comment: @MariusS.L. Thanks i understood. Hope my proof is correct now

Comment: @AleNekro97 Looks good now.